# Stop location.hash of frame's parent from reloading page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a frameset with to frames left/right. The content of the frame left the one below. As you can see, I want to update the hash/fragment identifier of the left frame's parent (the uppermost window) location.

However, this leads to reloading the whole frameset in Safari/Chrome. In Firefox, the whole frameset is not reloaded, but the browsers displays "loading" continuously.

Background: The left frame shows a navigation. A click in an entry loads another HTML page in the right frame and should also update the hash in the location of the browser window so the user can bookmark pages.

How can I make this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Left</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function go()
  {
    window.document.write('foo');  // replace document with 'foo'
    window.parent.location.hash = '#foo';
  }
</script>

<h1>Left</h1>
<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:go(); return false;">Go</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try changing:

`onclick="javascript:go(); return false;"`

...to something like:

`onclick="void(javascript:go(););"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.parent.location.hash` just try something like this:

**JS:**

```
function go()
{
  window.document.write('foo');  // replace document with 'foo'
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="#foo" onclick="go()">Go</a>
```

Comment: Will this not only change the left frame's fragment identifier?

Comment: The default target for links is `_self` which affects only a window from which is called.